# CellList with cells of CellTree

Tags: gwt, celllist

I used the gwt [CellList](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) example to implement a cell-based listbox. It used **TextCell** cells to represent the data, as **it was just text**, and worked perfectly.

Now I have to extend this list to **include elements of type "tree"** (I mean that you can click on some element of the list, and if it's not a leaf, it is opened and displays the information of its children). So I've implemented a CellTree-based widget. ([CellTree)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#celltree)

My problem is that I don't know how to insert items of type "tree", which are really CellTrees, into my CellList.

The only approach I could imagine was to create a new type of cell that represents the CellTree, extending "AbstractCell", and use it as the CellList items.

My implementation is:

```
private class TreeCell extends AbstractCell<CellTreeListBox> {

    public TreeCell() {}

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, CellTreeListBox value,
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
    {
      sb.appendEscaped(value.getElement().getInnerHTML());
    }
}
```

This, once included in a CellList, displays only the root nodes, but when I click on them they don't get opened! so this approach doesn't keep the events neither the functionality of the selectionModel...

So I don't know if it's possible to implement a cell that represents a whole CellTree, and keeps its events and functionalities (if you click, the node is opened and information of its children is displayed, etc...).

I'd really appreciate any information about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **replace** your `CellList` with a `CellTree`.

Either that or replacing the `CellList` with some container panel (`FlowPanel`, `VerticalPanel`) in which you'd (manually) put widgets (`Label`s, or possibly `CellWidget` with a `TextCell`), and insert your `CellTree` in between them to show it. You'd then lose the other features of cell widgets though: `SelectionModel`, paging, etc.

In any case, ditch your `CellList`. You cannot embed widgets inside cell widgets.

Comment: Yeah! thanks for your quick response, Thomas. I was expecting that a CellTree could be "converted" to a custom Cell and then be used as an element of a CellList, but I see in your comment that's not possible... What I didn't want to lose was the features of the CellList example in the showcase: the information shown in the list is incremented when the user scrolls down. I supose I can implement this by inserting a single CellTree, containing all the information, into a ScrollPanel, you think so?

Comment: You won't have the lazy-loading behavior but yes, that's possible. `CellTree` has paging built-in, but it's made through a _Show more_ button at the bottom of a branch.

Comment: I've just seen the "Show more" behavior, but that's not what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for you response, this matter has been a really headache U_U